# Oracle logs filled with "java.lang.Throwable: No Error"?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have enabled JDBC logging for my Oracle connection. I would like the log to only contain the text of executed queries, but it is filled with the below error.

Any suggestions for what may be causing this trace, how I can fix it, and/or how I can limit my logging to the text of executed queries?

> ```
> java.lang.Throwable: No Error
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1624)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4347)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4426)
>   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:4733)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyFactory.invoke(PreparedStatementProxyFactory.java:125)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
>   at com.me.MyClass.doQuery(MyClass.java:56)
>   at org.apache.jsp.jsp.secure.b2f.b2flogin_jsp._jspService(b2flogin_jsp.java:686)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
>   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

My OraceLog.properties

```
oracle.jdbc.level=CONFIG
oracle.jdbc.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=CONFIG
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = /tmp/jdbc.log
```

**Edit**

After using the JDBC logging a bit for debugging my applications, I have found the trace is useful, as it indicates code locations of SQL statements. And it can be easily filtered out with regex like:

> tail -f /tmp/jdbc.log | grep -v 'java.lang.*\|.*at.*’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a known side-effect of tracing SQL statements (`.level=CONFIG` and finer).  It is discussed in the comments on  [Enabling Oracle JDBC Driver Debug](https://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.com/2011/02/enabling-oracle-jdbc-driver-debug.html).  The last post there was in 2012.

There does not seem to be a way to disable the stack trace.

Comment: And I won't get sql query text without `level=config`? So I will be unable to log my queries without this stacktrace?

Comment: That does seem to be the case.  I could not find anything more recent than 2012.  You might want to file a bug with Oracle.

Comment: There haven't been any significant changes to Oracle Database JDBC logging from 2012 up through the most recent release.

Answer (score 2):

Write a java.util.logging.Filter that does nothing with No Error log messages and attach it to your Handler. Note that the Throwable is not thrown. It's just a hack to get the stack trace.

Oracle Database JDBC logging is a tool intended for debugging, not production. It's a huge performance drain. We strongly discourage using it in production. Our experience is that customers who want to see the SQL also want to see where it came from. That's why the stack trace.

Comment: After using a bit, I have found the No Error traces to be helpful, and easily filtered out with regex